# Find the whole number without a pair

Tags: algorithms

Is there a mathematical formula to determine within an entry of $N$ numbers that are repeated and a number that is not repeated what is the number that is not repeated?

Example, given the numbers $2,3,4,3,2,1,1$ find the number $4$ which is the whole number without a pair.

Comment: For sure, but also probably not a useful one. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Do all the other numbers occur exactly twice (or an even number of times)? If so, this is famously given by taking the bitwise XOR of the whole list, also called the [nim-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim). This can be calculated in linear time using constant memory.

Comment: Hi @Phicar it is just for curiosity. I tried to solve it using math operations but I had to use XOR.

Answer (score 0):

Using $P(X) = \prod_{k=1..n} (X-a_k)$, then $P(X)/gcd(P(X), P'(X))^2$ will give you $X - a_i$, with $a_i$ being the term that is not repeated.

In PARI/GP, this could be implemented as this:

```
seq = [2,3,4,3,2,1,1]
pol = vecprod(apply(v -> X-v, seq))
der = deriv(pol)
g = gcd(pol,der)
print (pol/g^2)
```

The output being:

```
X - 4
```

Comment: There is a way to represent it using code language?